# Adding dissimilar objects to Coredata

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have different attributes in my coredata model like shipping method, factor mode etc. given like so in the image below...

[image]

I have an entity called `Shipping` with attributes `shipping method`, `factor`, `mode`, `transport`. Since these values are dissimilar, I'm confused...

After saving to coredata, my first object should have the values `SHIP BY AIR(ELOC)` for `shipping method` `40` for `Factor` ,`AIR` for `Mode` and so on...

If it would have been a single value then I could have done something like so...

```
do {
    let managedContext = persistentContainer.viewContext
    let newitem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Values", into: managedContext)
    newitem.setValue("12",forKey: "custom")
    newitem.setValue("0.5",forKey: "ibaseCost")

     self.valueDetails.append(newitem as! Values)
     try managedContext.save()

 } catch {
 }
```

But in my present scenario, how can I store into Coredata...?

Comment: So what issues are you facing in storing the data.?

Comment: I'm not able to store data in this case...

Comment: have added the code to store the data my way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Adding the Data to core data:

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
let ship = Shipping(context: context) // Link Task & Context
ship.shippingmethod = "yourvalue"
ship.factor = "yourvalue"
ship.mode = "yourvalue"
ship.transport = "yourvalue"

// Save the data to coredata
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
```

**If your issue is just storing, this will solve it**

Hope this helps.

### Edit Demo of adding multiple Data

```
var shippindData = [
        ["shippingMethod":"ELOC","Factor":40,"Mode":"AIR","Transport":"Y"],
        ["shippingMethod":"VLOC","Factor":40,"Mode":"AIR","Transport":"Y"],
        ["shippingMethod":"ELOC","Factor":35,"Mode":"MIXED MODE","Transport":"Y"]]

    for data in shippindData{

        let innerData = data as! [String:Any]
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        let ship = Shipping(context: context) // Link Task & Context
        ship.shippingmethod = innerData["shippingMethod"]
        ship.factor = innerData["Factor"]
        ship.mode = innerData["Mode"]
        ship.transport = innerData["Transport"]

        // Save the data to coredata
        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
    }
```

You can use this logic to create an Data like this and add it using `for-loop`

Comment: ok..but this is for data in one row. how will i store the next set of values in the next row..?

Comment: use for loop logic to add it. Like store them in an dictonaries and use them to add. Lemme make a one for you. Wait

Comment: @v.bw Edited the answer for you, Lemme know if it works for you or not.?

Comment: @v.bw if it worked for you will be really appreciated if you approve that with an upVote.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solution may help you

Create a managed object file for your entity

**Swift**:

```
public class YourEntityName: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged public var custom: String

}
```

**ObjC**:

```
@interface YourEntityName : NSManagedObject

@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString * custom; //follow the same for other columns

@end

@implementation YourEntityName

@dynamic custom; //follow the same for other columns

@end
```

Just add the property of your managedObject in your swift/Obj C file. When you want to save, use the code snippet

```
    YourEntityName = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: ",into: "YourEntityName" appDelegateObject.managedObjectContext) as! YourEntityName

    YourEntityName.entity1 = "1"
    YourEntityName.entity2 = "2"
    YourEntityName.entity3 = "3"
    YourEntityName.entity4 = "4"

    self.yourManagedDelegateObject.saveContext()
```

make sure you use a coreData managed object wrapper class